# How do you call controller injections called again when changing from child route?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-scope

I want to parent controller to resolve its injection again when state changes from child to parent.

```
    .state('settings.billing', {
        url: '/billing',
        controller: 'BillingCtrl as vm',
        template: require('./templates/billing.tpl.jade'),
        resolve: {
            sources: function(StripeService) {
                return StripeService.getSources();
            }
        }
    })
    .state('settings.billing.newsource', {
        url: '/add-source',
        onEnter: showAddSourceModal
    })


function showAddSourceModal($state, $modal) {
    $modal.open({
        template: require('./templates/add-source.tpl.jade')(),
        controller: 'AddSourceCtrl as vm',
        backdrop: true,
        keyboard: true,
        size: 'md'
    })
    .result
    .finally(function() {
        $state.go('^');
    });
}
```

Basically I want sources for BillingCtrl called again when modal is closed. Is it possible?

Comment: try this `$state.go('^', {reload: true});`

Comment: Yeah this seems what I want. `$state.go('^',  {}, {reload: true});` @JesusCarrasco